# Decoding a URL with valid query

Tags: java, url, java-11

I have the following code snippet that decodes URLs in Java:

```
public URL decodeURL(String url) {
    try {
        return new URL(URLDecoder.decode(url, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

So for the following URL `"path/to/testurl/encoding?param=1&encodedQueryParam=table%3Dtask%5EORtableISEMPTY"` I'm supposed to get `"path/to/testurl/encoding?param=1&encodedQueryParam=table=task^ORtableISEMPTY"` but I'm getting `"/path/to/testurl/encoding"`.

How can I get the correct result?

Comment: Despite the name, URLDecoder is not for decoding URLs—it’s for decoding HTML form data submitted using the application/x-www-form-urlencoded format.  To decode a URL, using the [URI](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html) class.  (A URL is a type of URI.)  For example, `new URI(url).toURL()`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, when I run your code locally, I got exception with `java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol`

Then I add `https://` to the example url.

Finally I got the right result, the diff of codes is the charset param
so I think maybe it's the wrong import of URLDecoder class?

```java
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLDecoder;


public void test() throws Exception{
        System.out.println(decodeURL("https://path/to/testurl/encoding?param=1&encodedQueryParam=table%3Dtask" +
                "%5EORtableISEMPTY"));
    }

    public URL decodeURL(String url) {
        try {
            return new URL(URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8"));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e.getMessage());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

console log follows:

```
https://path/to/testurl/encoding?param=1&encodedQueryParam=table=task^ORtableISEMPTY
```

Answer (score 0):

The `URL.getPath()` method does not include the query paramater as the result. You will need to access it separatelly.

Example:

```
StringBuilder fullPath = new StringBuilder(url.getPath());
if(url.getQuery() != null) {
      fullPath.append("?").append(url.getQuery());
}
```

Comment: I think the issue is related to the Decoding